# Registered Apple Developer Agreement when under 18

Tags: developer-program

When I registered to be an Apple Developer, I inadvertently did so without realizing the requirement to be 18 years of age (I was 17 and 6 months away from being 18 at the time). I did not take out any sort of paid membership at the time, however.

I am now 20, will this cause me any problems now or is it nothing I need to worry about?

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but you're of legal age now, and that's what matters. I think Apple's legal department has much bigger things to worry about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You of legal age now, and meet the current age requirement of the agreement with Apple, so there's nothing to worry about.